# Updating list w/user submitted content

Tags: javascript, forms, comments

I couldn't find anything online to help me, likely because of how I'm wording this.

I want to create a page that has a list of reviews. The each review will consist of a 0-10 rating and a comment.

I can create an "add review" form, but how will i automatically add that review to the html unordered-list of reviews on that page?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<ul id="reviews">
    <li>5 stars - comment</li>
    <li>5 stars - comment</li>
    <li>5 stars - comment</li>
    <li>5 stars - comment</li>
    <li>5 stars - comment</li>
    <li>5 stars - comment</li>
</ul>
```

Can you please use JQuery? (Everyone should be using it at this point). To add to a list of elements like this you would just do:

```
$('#reviews').append('<li>new review stuff</li>');
```

Also, you didn't mention it, but I'm assuming you'd also want to add this to your database, so you'd need to do some sort of server based call (most likely AJAX), before you add it to the list, and the user "assumes" everything worked fine.

Comment: *Can you please use JQuery? (Everyone should be using it at this point)* -1. Nobody needs this kind of evangelism.

Comment: @Kooilnc - he didn't express any reason he didn't want to go with JQuery, which made me assume he was just unaware of it, and it's a great technology that is included standard now within the .NET web frameworks, why shouldn't everyone use it unless they have a reason not to?

Comment: It's a great technology *for you* and I suppose a lot of people. Inclusion in the .NET framework is not an argument to tell people they **should** use it. An argument against starting with jquery that many people nowadays seem to think jquery *is* javascript. It's a handy framework to avoid browser compatibility issues, but there's a world of such frameworks to be found, some better, some worse. I have become pretty allergic to all framework evangelism. First learn basic (non DOM) javascript, than pick and learn a framework I would advise.